# Intercepting by type AspectJ java

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I'm new in AOP aspectJ and Spring in Java,
I'd like to ask if aspectJ intercepting by Type would be possible.

```
@After("execution(* *.*.*.*.*.findAll(..))")
private void afterGet() {
    logger.info("Persons Listed");
}
```

The code above is used for intercepting the findAll() method, I'd like to know if intercepting by Integer, double is possible ?. for the return type or even if the type is called within the program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

To match return types:

```
execution(public int *.*.*(..))
execution(public double *.*.*(..))
```

Or parameters:

```
execution(public * *.*.*(int))
execution(public * *.*.*(double))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes ofcourse , we can intercept methods in Spring using AspectJ through

- Access Modifiers
- Return Types
- Formal Parameters

Go through the below link for getting a clear view and know how to intercept methods using different forms of PointCut expressions in AspectJ.

http://codemodeweb.blogspot.in/2018/03/spring-aop-and-aspectj-framework.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!